# What is the probability that randomly selected $2$ pets from this vet are cat or sick? Why doesnt addition rule for probability work?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-theory, solution-verification, problem-solving

> There are $7$ dogs and $6$ cats in a vet. $2$ of the dogs and $2$ of the cats are sick.What is the probability that randomly selected $2$ pets from this vet are cat or sick ?

My approach : Let the set of cats (sick and normal cats)called "A" and the set of sick pets (sick dogs and cats) called "B" ,then $$P(A \cup B)=P(A)+P(B)-P(A \cap B)=\frac{\binom{6}{2}}{\binom{13}{2}}+\frac{\binom{4}{2}}{\binom{13}{2}}-\frac{\binom{2}{2}}{\binom{13}{2}}=20/78$$

My friends'approach : The set of $A \cup B$ have $8$ elements in it , so the answer is $$\frac{\binom{8}{2}}{\binom{13}{2}}=28/78$$

Who is right here ? .. Can you help me ?

**Addentum** : By comments of @L.F. ,I saw that my calculation does not contain the probability of selecting a normal cat and a sick dog. However , i cannot understand why , i applied addition rule of probability. Moreover , related question in [this page](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/a/additionruleforprobabilities.asp) confirms me.

Comment: Your approach ignores the possibility of picking a sick cat and a non-sick cat, which belongs to neither $\binom{6}{2}$ nor $\binom{4}{2}$.

Comment: @L.F. My calculation includes it , C(6,2) includes it

Comment: Sorry, I meant picking a sick *dog* and a non-sick *cat*.

Comment: @L.F. yes it seems reasonable , however , i apply *[additive law property](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/a/additionruleforprobabilities.asp)* .Please check this page , there is very similar example in that page , and confirm my result.

Comment: You have correctly computed $P(A\cup B)$ where $A$ is the event that you pick two cats and $B$ is the event that you pick two sick pets. Your mistake is that you chose to compute that probability. It is not what the question asked.

Comment: To elaborate on David K's comment: you are trying to pick a pair of animals, but $A$ and $B$ (and thus $A \cap B$ and $A \cup B$) are sets of individual animals.  $P(A)$, $P(B)$, etc. are meaningless.

Comment: @DavidK why compute their probability is a mistake ? yes i see that it does not include some cases but according to addition rule and the example in given link apply addition rule. Can you elaborate it ?

Comment: In order to be able to write $P(A)$, $A$ has to be an *event*, something that might occur or not occur. You called the set of cats "A", but what has to *occur* in order for you to say the event $A$ has occurred? According to your calculations, the event $A$ is "we randomly selected two pets and both were cats." And event $B$ is "we randomly selected two pets and both were sick." Then $A\cup B$ is, "we randomly selected two pets and they both were cats or they both were sick."

Answer (score 2):

As the comments indicated, your analysis went astray.

$~\displaystyle \binom{6}{2}~$ equals the number of ways of selecting $2$ cats, out of $6$ cats.

$~\displaystyle \binom{4}{2}~$ equals the number of ways of selecting $2$ sick pets out of $4$ sick pets.

Your enumeration of $~\displaystyle \binom{6}{2} + \binom{4}{2} - \binom{2}{2}~$ represents

the union of selecting $2$ cats, and $2$ sick pets.

In other words, your enumeration represents either:

- selecting $2$ cats, that may or may not be sick
- selecting $2$ sick pets, that may or may not be cats
- or both.

However, the above options are not the only ways that you can select 2 pets, with neither pet being a **non-sick** dog.  That is, you can select one dog that is sick, and one cat that is not sick.  This specific option is not included in your enumeration of $~\displaystyle \binom{6}{2} + \binom{4}{2} - \binom{2}{2}.~$

---

In case what I said doesn't clarify the situation,

let $A$ denote the set of all combinations of $2$ cats.

Let $B$ denote the set of all combinations of $2$ sick pets.

You enumerated $A \cup B$.

However, consider the case of $1$ well cat and $1$ sick dog.  This case is not included in either set $A$ or set $B$.

Comment: The comments and addentum said what you wrote already , i am asking for why addition rule does not work

Comment: @user0203457689 I just added a trailing explanation to my answer.  Does this resolve your questions?  If not, what specifically are you referring to by the **addition rule**?

Comment: your answer restate what is already written before. It did not help me.

Comment: @user0203457689 How else can I explain it?

Comment: Firstly thanks for you helps , but i want to understand why addition rule of probability does not work here . I know that it cannot include sick dog and normal cat , then why ? As you see  , i gave a link in comments and addentum. There are ver similar question there  , it is about girls and grade B. When we select one individual in that question , both my method and my friends method work correctly. However  , when we select more than once objects , my method fails because of ignoring some cases.

Comment: @user0203457689 I think that the explanation is that your *addition rule*, for the present problem enumerates $A \cup B$ as described in the back half of my answer.  However $A \cup B$ is not the requested enumeration.  This is the only explanation that I can offer.

Comment: my question is not duplicate ...

Comment: @user0203457689 Please re-phrase your last comment.  I don't understand the significance of "my question is not duplicate".

Comment: @user2661923 OP asked a question concerning the exact same conceptual error [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4460590/139123), and said it is not a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

Let us first go back to the very basic concept of probability by counting
$\dfrac{\text {favorable points in sample space}}{\text{total points in sample space}}$

Favorable points in sample space $= n(A\cup B) = n(A)+n(B) - n(A\cap B) = 6+4-2 = 8$
Total points in sample space $= 8+5 = 13$
Pr $=\dfrac{\binom82}{\binom{13}2} = \dfrac{28}{78}$

For the probability law to be valid, the union of the defined events must not miss any favorable sample point.

Here, as has already been pointed out, $A\cup B$ as defined by you misses out one ok cat + one sick dog, so your computation works out lower.

To correct for this, you will need to redefine/add events, but it is **both safer and simpler** to instead use

$Pr = \dfrac{\text {favorable points in sample space}}{\text{total points in sample space}}$