# Mistake in "addition rule" in probability theory.

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-theory, discrete-mathematics

> Theorem : Let $E_1$ and $E_2$ be events in sample space S. Then , $P(E_1 \cup E_2) =P(E_1)+P(E_2)-P(E_1 \cap E_2)$

> Question: What is the probability that a positive integer selected at random from the set of positive integers not exceeding $100$ is divisible by either $2$ or $5$ ?

First way : Select one element from the set which satisfies "divisible by either $2$ or $5$". There are $60$ elemens which divisible by either $2$ or $5$ in that set ,so $C(60,1)/(100,1)=3/5$

Second way: Use the theorem such that $P(E_1 \cup E_2) =P(E_1)+P(E_2)-P(E_1 \cap E_2)= (50/100)+(20/100)-(10/100)=60/100$ where $E_1$ is the elements divisible by $2$ , $E_2$ is the elements divisible by $5$.

The both ways work correctly.No problem !

**However,** when we want to select two or more elements , the second way is incorrect.Let solve it for selecting two elements:

First way : Select one element from the set which satisfies "divisible by either $2$ or $5$". There are $60$ elemens in that set ,so $C(60,2)/(100,2)=1770/C(100,2)$

Second way: Use the theorem such that $P(E_1 \cup E_2) =P(E_1)+P(E_2)-P(E_1 \cap E_2)= [C(50,2)/C(100,2)]+[C(20,2)/C(100,2)]-[C(10,2)/C(100,2)] =1370/ C(100,2)$

When we select only one element , the theorem gives correct answer , but when we select more than once ,the theorem  misses some situations.

- Why does it happen ,i.e why the second case is missing some elements?
- If the theorem may miss some cases , is it unreliable in some cases. If so , which cases are unreliable ?
- Should we use the theorem only the cases where only one element is selected ?

Thanks in advance !!

Comment: my question is not duplicate , can you reopen it ?

Comment: before closing a question ,  READ it !!!

Comment: Can you be clear what the second problem is? Also you should be explicit what $E_1$ and $E_2$ are defined as.

Comment: @AlanAbraham which second problem ? $E_1$ and $E_2$ is defined clearly

Comment: The error in the second calculation is **exactly** the same error as in the question you asked just a few hours earlier. And once again the problem is you take a probability $P(\cdot)$ **without** clearly understanding what the thing in the parentheses is. An event is not just a set of integers.

Comment: For what it's worth, I think that the reactions of MathSE reviewers to your question(s) have been overly harsh.  In both this question, and the related question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4460464/what-is-the-probability-that-randomly-selected-2-pets-from-this-vet-are-cat-or/4460497), as a Math student new to the topic, you were challenged by a subtlety.  In fact it is the same subtlety that is triggering the same error.  However, from your perspective, as a new student, this is (I feel) reasonably regarded as irrelevant.  ...see next comment

Comment: The situation is confusing to you and the only long term solution is to stretch your intuition.  This can only be done through Math exercises.  In fact, **this is exactly what you are doing**!  Exploring various Math problems to *experience* the flaw in your intuition helps you develop fluency.  Please do not be discouraged by the reactions of the other MathSE reviewers.

Comment: The text of this question actually would have been worthwhile to insert as an "edit" of the previous question, because it gives a little more detail pointing to the source of your confusion. I still don't believe it is good for the questions to be posed separately, but adding detail and background to an existing question (especially when you're not getting answers you understand yet) is encouraged. You could still edit the original question to include the details you have here, or ask a moderator to merge the questions.

Comment: @DavidK I think that we should agree to disagree.  For one thing, the two questions are different enough so that the OP (i.e. original poster) is not breaking protocol by posting the 2nd question separately.  For another, given the OP's attempt to grapple with the challenge, the cleanest approach for the OP is to post the 2nd question separately (i.e. independently of the 1st).  The fact that the conceptual error is identical isn't relevant (to me at least).  What is relevant is that the OP is doing exactly what he is supposed to do to learn the Math.

Comment: @user2661923 I admit I am a bit torn, because if we could only answer one of the two questions, I would prefer to answer this one: it is much better supported by research and the OP's own efforts. The conceptual error is present in the "select one element" case too, but in a much more subtle way which I'm afraid we will not be able to correct at this rate.

Comment: I don't have a problem with seeing this as novel enough to avoid being a duplicate (although I see the similarity).  I do have a problem with how the "second question", the one for which the addition formula supposedly doesn't work, is presented.  Evidently the OP want to select two elements with the given divisibility property, but states this as "First way : Select one element from the set which satisfies...".  If the OP edits the Question I'll be happy to reopen and answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is the probability of E = {two numbers, both of them are either 2 divided or 5 divided}

You also define $E_1$ = {two numbers, both of them are 2 divided} and $E_2$ = {two numbers, both of them are 5 divided}

The problem is $E\neq E_1\cup E_2$. To see this, suppose you select (2,5), this event belongs to $E$, not belongs to either of $E_1$ and $E_2$.

To correct the gap, you need to consider $E_3$ = {two numbers, one of them is only 2 divided, the other is only 5 divided}. Hence $E = (E_1\cup E_2)\cup E_3$. Because $E_3$ is disjoint from $E_1\cup E_2$, we have

\begin{equation}
P(E) = P((E_1\cup E_2)\cup E_3) = P(E_1\cup E_2) + P(E_3)
\end{equation}

To count the cases in $E_3$, it is $40\times 10 = 400$. This is because there are 40 numbers that are 2 divided but not 5 divided, and there are 10 numbers that are 5 divided but not 2 divided.